# How to work with asset images in carousel_slider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is where I call the widget and try to pass in a List of widgets with the Pictures in.

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
           child: CarouselSlider(
               options: CarouselOptions(
             aspectRatio: 2.0,
             enlargeCenterPage: true,
             enableInfiniteScroll: false,
             initialPage: 2,
             autoPlay: false,
            ),
             items: imageSliders,
          )),
```

Thats the list of widgets.

```
final List<String> imgList = [
  'images/shoppinglist_main.jpg',
  'images/shoppinglist_main.jpg'
];

final List<Widget> imageSliders = imgList
    .map((item) => Container(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0.0,
                      left: 0.0,
                      right: 0.0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0),
                              Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          ),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'No. ${imgList.indexOf(item)} image',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ))
    .toList();
```

Here is the error message:

Null is not a subtype of Future.
This will become a failure when runtime null safety is enabled.
Restarted application in 63ms.
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderAspectRatio has unbounded constraints.
This RenderAspectRatio was given an aspect ratio of 2 but was given both unbounded width and
unbounded height constraints. Because both constraints were unbounded, this render object doesn't
know how much size to consume.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  AspectRatio

Can someone please give me a hint on how to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because both constraints were unbounded, this render object doesn't
>   know how much size to consume.

You can assign a constraint like this:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 250, //here your width
  height: 250, //here your height
  child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            enableInfiniteScroll: false,Ï
            initialPage: 2,
            autoPlay: false,
          ),
             items: imageSliders,
        )
   )
```